# Android Jetpack Compose: How to Prevent a Pinned Dynamic Shortcut from Getting Updated?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-shortcut, pinned-shortcut, android-dynamic-shortcuts

- I'm working on an Android app using Jetpack Compose, and I've
  implemented dynamic shortcuts using ShortcutManagerCompat
  (pushDynamicShortcut).
- These shortcuts get updated automatically when the underlying data
  changes, which is the default behavior.
- However, I have a specific use case where I want to prevent a
  particular pinned shortcut from getting updated when the data
  changes.

Is there a way to achieve this in Android Jetpack Compose? How can I selectively control the update behavior of dynamic shortcuts which is in a pinned state?